# Error in MVC 2 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting the following error in my MVC application and all my debugging can seem to identify where it is originating. I have done undo to all the changes i made in that particular page and I still get this error. However, I am using quite a number of hidden fields in page..could that cause this error and if so how do I resolve?

```
 System.Web.HttpUnhandledException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown."
  Source="System.Web"
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl.RenderViewAndRestoreContentType(ViewPage containerPage, ViewContext viewContext)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext)
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView.RenderViewUserControl(ViewContext context, ViewUserControl control)
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
       at ASP.views_paymentapplications_next_aspx.__RenderContent2(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\ProjectsVisualStudio\Projects\.NET 3.5\Pound\ExceptionManager\ExceptionManager\app\ExceptionManager.Web\Views\PaymentApplications\Next.aspx:line 39
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at ASP.views_shared_site_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\ProjectsVisualStudio\Projects\.NET 3.5\Pound\ExceptionManager\ExceptionManager\app\ExceptionManager.Web\Views\Shared\Site.Master:line 466
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
       Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
       Source="App_Web_lhjnw8uq"
       StackTrace:
            at ASP.views_paymentapplications_paymentapplicationform_ascx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\ProjectsVisualStudio\Projects\.NET 3.5\Pound\ExceptionManager\ExceptionManager\app\ExceptionManager.Web\Views\PaymentApplications\PaymentApplicationForm.ascx:line 98
            at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
            at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
            at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
            at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
            at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
            at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
            at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
            at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
            at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
            at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
            at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
            at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
            at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: And you didn't find it necessary to show your code? You have a NullReferenceException which means that you are trying to access an object which is null and this happens in your `paymentapplicationform.ascx` partial. That's all I can say from this stacktrace but I suppose this doesn't help you much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post the code that is in the following stack trace:

> InnerException:
>   System.NullReferenceException
>   Message="Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object."
>   Source="App_Web_lhjnw8uq" StackTrace:
>   at
>   ASP.views_paymentapplications_paymentapplicationform_ascx._Render_control1(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\ProjectsVisualStudio\Projects.NET
>   3.5\Pound\ExceptionManager\ExceptionManager\app\ExceptionManager.Web\Views\PaymentApplications\PaymentApplicationForm.ascx:line
>   98

Using my psychic debug powers, I'm guessing that:

You're sending an object that is 'null' to a RenderPartial, and it can't render the partial. So check the setter for that thing you're sending to the RenderPartial, and see if it's null.

Comment: Do I obtain this information by drill down on the error??

Comment: It says the problem is in line 98 of the `PaymentAPplicationForm.ascx`.  I'm guessing that you're sending a 'null' to a RenderPartial, and it can't render the partial. So check the setter for that thing you're sending to the RenderPArtial, and see if it's null.

Comment: I see where it is null...the problem is this error is intermittent. I will go a day without seeing it. Next thing I have it like 5 times in a minute.

Comment: @JamaicasFinest Ok, then something that is setting that Model is at some point null; so I'd start writing unit tests for that section of code and see what circumstances make it null.